# How to select the particular web element from the HTML code below using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Below is the HTML code and how to select element wither by using xpath or css selector

```
<button class="btn btn-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-repeat="ext in _view.getNonEmptyChildren()" ng-click="_navigate(ext.$id, _route.objectId, { 'navigator' : _route.navigator,
               'relatedItemParentId': relatedItemParentId(ext.$parent)})" ng-class="{active: _view.getSelectedChild().$id == ext.$id}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'{ext[nameField]}'" aria-invalid="false">Clusters</button>
```

Comment: Please don't add code in comments like that, you can _edit_ the original question to add the code with correct formatting (highlight it all and click the `{}` button in the editor). It's hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-sm.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty[ng-model='radioModel'][ng-class*='getSelectedChild']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty' and @ng-model='radioModel'][contains(.,'Clusters')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```